# Regular expression to match a word without a character

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the question:

We have strings containing 2 words, like:

```
["bed time", "red carpet", "god father", "good game"]
```

The regex should match `god father` and `good game` because each of them have a word that does not contain the letter `e` (god and good), and it should not match `bed time` and "red carpet" as both words inside the strings have the letter `e`.

I was thinking about `/\b[^e]*\b/g` , but it matches all of these strings.

Answer (score 2):

This works for your case:

```
/.*\b[^\se]+\b.*/gi
```

**[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sO7zV6/5)**

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
/^(\w+ [^e]+|[^e ]+ \w+)$/i
```

It searches for either one of:

- words that may contain an 'e' and words that do not contain an 'e'
- words that do not contain an 'e' and words that may contain an 'e'

Note that `[a-z]` may be used in place of `\w` if that's what the solution requires.  Assuming that the examples are truly representative of the inputs, either should work adequately.

This code tests the regex against the input array:

```
phrases = ["bed time", "red carpet", "god father", "good game"]
phrases.each do |phrase|
  puts "#{phrase}" if phrase.match(/^(\w+ [^e]+|[^e ]+ \w+)$/i)
end
```

The results are:

```
god father
good game
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it did not answer the question. The regex is supposed to match `god father` and `good game`, but this regex does not.

Comment: @Sahar you are correct, and I've updated the regex to work as expected.  I've also added a short test program and shown the results of running it on the input array that you provided.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
/\b([^ e])+\b/gi
```

This selects any words that do not contain an e|E.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/\b[^\We]+\b/g
```

- `\W` means NOT a "word" character.
- `^\W` means a "word" character.
- `[^\We]` means a "word" character, but not an "e".

see it in action: [word without e](https://regexr.com/5s72r)

### "and" Operator for Regular Expressions

BTW, I think this pattern can be used as an "**and**" operator for regular expressions.

In general, if:

- `A = not a`
- `B = not b`

then:

```
[^AB] = not(A or B) 
      = not(A) and not(B) 
      = a and b
```

### Difference Set

So, if we want to implement the concept of [difference set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_set) in regular expressions, we could do this:

```
a - b = a and not(b)
      = a and B
      = [^Ab]
```