# Regex - Find first word without a specific string

Tags: regex

I want to analyse line of string. There are some bytes as hex code. To this i want to get the first word after these without the characters "0x".
The word after can contain a "x" but not as 0x.
e.g.: TimeStamp[ID] -> 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x7 0x88 0x98 0x76 0x5 Word_I_Searched_without

I have proofed:

[Regex excluding specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352038/regex-excluding-specific-characters)

[Regex: Match word not containing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159862/regex-match-word-not-containing)

[Regular expression to match a word without a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221600/regular-expression-to-match-a-word-without-a-character)

Comment: what flavour? and also could you add some examples

Comment: Please provide some input samples. Additionally, it might be easier to tackle the problem programwise (matching each word and analyze it then, that is).

Comment: e.g: TimeStamp[ID] -> 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x7 0x88 0x98 0x76 0x5 Word_I_Searched_without

Comment: Please update your original post to include a sample input string and sample output from that string.

Comment: This > `(?<=\b0x)[0-9]+\b`? It's hard to tell what you are after without expected return.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to use a so called word boundary, if that is supported:

```
\b(?!0x)[0-9A-Fx]+\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/4FwE5V/2/).

Comment: Thx for the answer. I test yours but you see [here](https://regex101.com/r/4FwE5V/3) it doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

At least i changed my code. The result is that i used following regex with your input:

`(?<=-> )(.*?)(\b(?!0x)(?!\s+)+.*)`

Thanks for your help.